# play-framework's PropertiesEnhancer: custom getters/setters won't be called

Tags: java, properties, playframework, getter-setter, playframework-2.3

I am using play-framework 2.3.9 for java and have an issue with play's property-enhancement:

As described in the [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/model), play uses byte-code enhancement to automatically create getters and setters for public fields. This feature is also supposed to support writing my own accessors:

> Of course you can define the getter and setter methods yourself. If a method exists Play will use the existing accessors.

However, **my custom getters/setters won't be called!**

This is an example from the play-documentation of an model with a custom setter:

```
public class Product {

    public String name;
    public Integer price;

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        if (price < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Price can’t be negative!");
        }
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

In another class I set a negative value for the `price`-property:

```
Product myProduct = new Product();
myProduct.price = -20;
```

With correct play enhancement this should automatically call the custom setter and an exception should be thrown. **But no exception is thrown!**

---

My first thought was that maybe play-enhancement is disabled by default, since this was also [discussed latley by the play developers](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/4264). So I had a look at the .class files with a decompiler and noticed, that all getters/setters are *created and called correctly* as long as no self-written accessor exists. So obviously play-enhancement is enabled.

I find it a bit strange, that play's documentation about this topic doesn't exist for any version higher than play-1.2. Is it possible that the play developers forgot to maintain this feature??

I have created a [git-hub repository](https://github.com/aschiffmann/play-enhancement-bug) which contains the exact code example from the play documentation that I have mentioned above, where you can reproduce the bug.

Am a missing anything?
What do I have to do, so that my custom accessor-code is called without having to explicitly call the getter/setter-methods?

Comment: Your link is to Play 1.2 documentation.  Play 2 is very different from Play 1.

Comment: @Ryan: As I said, I was not able to find any documentation about that topic for a higher version! Did you?

Comment: I had a look at play's source-code and found out, that the enhancer only replaces the code to use the setter of a field, if the field has the annotation @PropertiesEnhancer.GeneratedSetAccessor. When I add this annotation to the field, everything works as expected. I have committed this "fix" in the repository in the branch "workaround". I guess it must be a bug in play?

Comment: try with myProduct.setPrice(-20);

Comment: Documentation is [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaEbean).  There is specific discussion of property generation.

Comment: Are you by chance using EBean too? I had a problem with accessors, described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120020/manytomany-query-using-play-and-ebean)

Comment: @Sam: apparently that's in fact how you are supposed to use the Setter, you have to call it explicitly. Play Developers [don't think that this is a bug](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4504), the behaviour in play-1.x and play-2.x is simply different they say.